# PHPUnit 4 - TestCase subclass autoloading

Tags: php, phpunit

I need to add some assertions and some default before/after methods to all my testcases.

According to [the phpunit docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/4.8/en/extending-phpunit.html) I should subclass `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase` but when I do this I end up having to write a bootstrap file for phpunit.

Does PHPUnit autoloading allow me to simply drop it in my tests folder with a specific filename or is it really required to make a bootstrap file?

Comment: Use traits to incorporate your assertions and your setup/teardown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `autoload-dev` in composer for autoloading custom classes. PHPUnit 4 as installed through composer [doesn't support running outside of composer](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/4.8/phpunit#L40)